# Проблема с триггером в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Сделал триггер на обновление данных.
Когда я делаю данный запрос на обновление данных

```
update cash
    set spent = 1000
where id = 1;
```

Все нормально, но как только я создаю триггер на данную операцию, то данный запрос не выполняется и появляется ошибка:
SQL Error [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 'cash.spent' in 'field list', хотя данная колонка есть в таблице.
Триггер вот:

```
drop trigger if exists bonuses_count;
delimiter //
create trigger bonuses_count after update on cash
for each row
begin
    update bonuses
        set c_bonuses = cash.spent / 1000;
end //
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: cash действительно в триггере нигде не объявлена. Значения колонок после обновления внутри триггера доступны как `:NEW.spent ` А вообще update внутри триггера выглядит странным, вы действительно хотите после обновления одной _ЛЮБОЙ_ записи cash записать ее spent/1000 в c_bonuses _ВСЕХ_ записей таблицы bonuses. Т.е. в результирующей таблице будет значение из последней измененной записи cash

Comment: Нет, я хотел не так. 
Я хотел чтобы c_bonuses таблица менялась только по тому ID, колонка spent которого изменилась

Comment: тогда стоит добавить в update условие where

Comment: ```
where old.spent != new.spent;
```

Comment: Попробовал добавить это
Если вам не сложно, то можете помочь с этим вопросом?

Comment: А как я вам помогу если структуры таблиц не известны, так же как и конечная цель совершаемых действий. И в общем то запрос внутри триггера ничем не отличается от любых других запросов. Просто надо иметь ввиду, что новые значения колонок изменяемой таблицы доступны через `:NEW`, а значения которые были до изменения через `:OLD`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Я новый в MySQL, решил свою задачу с помощью

Comment: ```
drop trigger if exists bonuses_count;
delimiter //
create trigger bonuses_count after update on cash
for each row
begin
 update bonuses
  set c_bonuses = new.spent / 1000
 where user_id = new.user_id;
end //

update cash
 set spent = 1123124
where id = 10;

select * from cash;

select * from bonuses;